# MongoDB Deployed on Raspberry Pi Timing out on Nodejs Server with SSL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, raspberry-pi, ssl-certificate

I recently deployed my nodejs server along with mongoDb on a raspberry pi and everything works fine but the mongoDB requests are timing out. I believe the error has something to do with the ssl as when I remove the SSL it works fine.

The error I get is on any api request I make to the server is:

```
{"message":"Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms"}
```

My connection string for mongodb is:

```
  "connectionString":"mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017?authSource=dbWithUserCredentials&compressors=zlib&retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true"
```

The connection code in the server is:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || config.get('connectionString'), {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true},(err,client)=>{
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log('Connected to database');
});
```

my server.js is:

```
require('rootpath')();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var exec = require('exec');
const jwt = require('./clover-server-backend/_helpers/jwt');
const errorHandler = require('./clover-server-backend/_helpers/error-handler');

var https = require('https');

var fs = require('fs');

var options = {

  key: fs.readFileSync('./src/assets/ssl_key.txt'),

  cert: fs.readFileSync('./src/assets/sll.com.crt'),

  ca: fs.readFileSync ('./src/assets/ssl.com.ca-bundle')

};

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/softServer', { dotfiles: 'allow' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(cors());

// app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
//
//   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/softServer/index.html'));
// });
// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use('/api/*', jwt());
// api routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./clover-server-backend/users/users.controller'));
app.use('/api/categories', require('./clover-server-backend/categories/categories.controller'));
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/softServer/index.html'));
});
// global error handler
app.use(errorHandler);
// start server
console.log('In server.js'); //*MES*
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 443 : 4000;
var server = https.createServer(options, app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server starting on port : " + port)
});

function execCallback(err,stdout, stderr){
  if(stdout){
    console.log(stdout)
  }
  if(stderr){
    console.log(stderr)
  }
}
```

Comment: You are hosting mongoDB on the same device as your node server. You don't need an ssl cert, your requests will never leave the device. If you must use ssl for some reason - there may be a problem with the cert, or how it is configured on mongodb. I would also recommend using `localhost` rather than `127.0.0.1` as having certs for IP addresses is very unusual

Comment: @caffeinated.tech thanks for the response but I tried it with local host and it did not work. I still get the timeout error

Comment: How have you setup the ssl cert on your mongodb? Can you share the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your database connection code is in your server.js and not an external file
if its in an external file make sure you call it in the server.js or it will not connect to the database

Answer (score 0):

You did not require your mongoose connection function did u? It's not in your server.js.

`findOne` command gets timed out because there isn't an active connection.

findOne gets queued until your server gets connected, and if there isn't an active connection it gets timed out.

You need to require the connection file, or call the mongoose connect in your server.js